# Filtering Pandas dataframe Group by count value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter the group by count from a pandas dataframe so I only end up with values over a certain amount.

Example dataframe:

| Name | Thing | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fred | Apple | 1 |
| Harry | Banana | 1 |
| Sonia | Banana | 1 |
| Pete | Apple | 1 |
| Tracy | Apple | 1 |

```
df.groupby(["Thing"]).sum()['Count']
```

Current output:

| Thing |  |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 3 |
| Banana | 2 |

But my desired output is to only include a *Thing* if the sum value is more than 2:

| Thing |  |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 3 |

I can only find examples of filtering df columns when using groupby. How do you filter based on the aggregated values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter it

```
out = df.groupby(["Thing"]).sum()['Count'].loc[lambda x : x>2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.query()`:

```
df.groupby('Thing').sum().query('Count > 2')['Count']
```